# CarrierWave Multi-uploader Renames Existing Files

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

I have followed the CarrierWave [documentation for multi-uploaders](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Add-more-files-and-remove-single-file-when-using-default-multiple-file-uploads-feature) and you can upload multiple files as expected, however if the user uploads files a second time the original files get moved from `file.png` to `file(2).png`, but the database record does not get updated, thereby preventing the image from being loaded.

How can I either prevent the existing files from being moved or update my model with the updated filename?

```rb
class ProfilePhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [250, 250]
  end

  # Add an allowlist of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_allowlist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    original_filename if original_filename.present?
  end
end
```

Controller:

```rb
profile_params = params.require(:profile).permit([portraits: []])
@profile.portraits += profile_params[:portraits] if profile_params[:portraits]
```

Model:

```rb
Class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    mount_uploaders :portraits, ProfilePhotoUploader
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I either prevent the existing files from being moved or update my model with the updated filename?

One approach would be to override the `filename` method in your uploader class to make sure the original filename remains unchanged even if the same file is uploaded again.
(you have a similar approach in [`carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave` issue 961](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/961#issuecomment-12611343) for a different problem)

```rb
def filename
  @name ||= "#{timestamp}-#{super}" if original_filename.present?
end

def timestamp
  var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
  model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
end
```

And, whenever a file is uploaded, you would update the model with the new filename in your controller.

```rb
def update
  profile_params = params.require(:profile).permit([portraits: []])
  @profile.portraits += profile_params[:portraits] if profile_params[:portraits]
  @profile.save
  @profile.portraits.each_with_index do |portrait, index|
    @profile.portraits[index].retrieve_from_store!(File.basename(portrait.file.file))
  end
end
```

Your code would be:

```rb
# Uploader
class ProfilePhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [250, 250]
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename
    @name ||= "#{timestamp}-#{super}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  def timestamp
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
  end
end

# Controller
def update
  profile_params = params.require(:profile).permit([portraits: []])
  @profile.portraits += profile_params[:portraits] if profile_params[:portraits]
  @profile.save
  @profile.portraits.each_with_index do |portrait, index|
    @profile.portraits[index].retrieve_from_store!(File.basename(portrait.file.file))
  end
end

# Model
Class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    mount_uploaders :portraits, ProfilePhotoUploader
    ...
end
```

---

The [OP Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811307/kevin) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77381818/carrierwave-multi-uploader-renames-existing-files/77393864#comment136463076_77393864):

> OK, this works, however with each upload the filename gets prefixed with a new timestamp, which will eventually overload the filename.
> My first inclination is to also add a unique string, eg `zzzz` and remove everything before it, but that seems pretty clunky.
>
> For now I'm going to do this:
>
> ```
> @name ||= "#{timestamp}-#{super.gsub(/^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d-/, "")}"
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: Okay, this works, however with each upload the filename gets prefixed with a new timestamp, which will eventually overload the filename. My first inclination is to also add a unique string, eg `zzzz` and remove everything before it, but that seems pretty clunky.

Comment: For now I'm going to do this:
`@name ||= "#{timestamp}-#{super.gsub(/^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d-/, "")}"`

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.